# "Third party sources disabled" when upgrading, why?

Tags: upgrade

When I tried to upgrade to 13.10, it was appearing on the screen while preparing to update

> Third party sources disabled
>
> Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager.

After that it was on:

```
W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Can someone please specify, where is "Software Sources" ?

Answer (score 2):

First message is to prevent problems with the upgrade. All 3rd party repositories get disabled to ensure a full and sucessful upgrade.

The second indicates that there was some problem in the mirror/download of the lists. Run `sudo apt-get update` or change mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Software Sources and add software sources by clicking on their checkboxes. Reinstall some of them if necessary.